# What is the maximum length of a SID in SDDL format

Tags: authentication, active-directory, sid

I'm building Active Directory Authentication into my application and I am planning to link my application's internal accounts to a user's domain SID.  It is easier for me to work with the string format of the sid than a byte array so I was planning to store it in the database as a string.  How long should I make the field to ensure SID's will not get truncated?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same question, and I believe the right answer is:

- ID as string: 184 characters, or varchar(184) in SQL Server
- SID as string of Hex digits:  136 characters, or varchar(136) in SQL Server
- SID as binary:  68 bytes, or varbinary(68) in SQL Server

I haven't checked the math myself, but the technique used here looks valid:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.dotnet.security/NpIi7c2Toi8/31SVhcepY58J

Refer to the program written by Russell Mangel on Aug 19, 2006, also copied here for reference:

> So the answer to my question is:
>
> varbinary(68)-- pure binary
>   varchar(136) -- (68*2) = hexString
>   varchar(184) -- SID String
>
> I wrote a little program to test,
>   notice that .NET 2.0 has
>   SecurityIdentifier.MaxBinaryLength, I
>   didn't know about this.
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine("SID Min. num Bytes: {0}",
> SecurityIdentifier.MinBinaryLength);
> Console.WriteLine("SID Max. num Bytes: {0}",
> SecurityIdentifier.MaxBinaryLength);
> Byte[] bytes = new byte[SecurityIdentifier.MaxBinaryLength];
> for (Int32 i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
> {
>     bytes[i] = 0xFF;
> }
> bytes[0] = 0x01; // Must be 1
> bytes[1] = 0x0F; // Max 15 (base10)
> SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(bytes, 0);
> String sidString = sid.ToString();
> Console.WriteLine("Max length of SID in String format: {0} ", sidString.Length);
> Console.WriteLine(sidString);
> ```
>
> Results
>
> ```
> SID Min. num Bytes: 8
> SID Max. num Bytes: 68
> Max length of SID in String format: 184
> S-1-281474976710655-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-
>   4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-
>   4294967295-4294967295-4294967295-4294967295
> ```

Comment: Can you explain, why SQL's SUSER_SID returns VARBINARY(85), not (68)?

Answer (score 2):

According to ntseapi_x.h:

```
typedef struct _SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY {
    UCHAR Value[6];
} SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY, *PSID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY; 

typedef struct _SID {
   UCHAR Revision;
   UCHAR SubAuthorityCount;
   SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY IdentifierAuthority;
   ULONG SubAuthority[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} SID, *PISID;
    
#define SID_MAX_SUB_AUTHORITIES          (15)
```

A *UCHAR* is actually an *unsigned char* which is 1 byte.  *ULONG* is an *unsigned long* which is 4 bytes.

**SID's max data size is 68 bytes**: UCHAR + UCHAR + (UCHAR * 6) + (ULONG * 15) = 1 + 1 + 6 + 60 = 68

Converting a SID to a string, like what you would get by calling [ConvertSidToStringSid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sddl/nf-sddl-convertsidtostringsidw), might look something like this: L"S-1-5-21-66"

- "S-1" <= is the start of all SIDs

  - 3 characters
- "5" <= is the identifier authority

  - the numbers are printed as decimals normally.  One exception is if the authority is larger 4 bytes, then it is printed as hex, eg. 0x1234...
  - So the max value would be "4294967296" or "0xffffffffffff" or 14 characters
- "21" & "66" <= are sub-authrities

  - Each can be up "4294967296" or 10 characters, with 15 max sub authorities
- the sections are delimited by a "-"

**SID's max string length is 184**: 3 + 1 + 14 + 1 + (10 * 15) + 14 = 183, or 184 counting the null.

You may consider just using MAX_UNICODE_STACK_BUFFER_LENGTH or 256 which fits nicely in memory.

Answer (score 1):

183. For string format, the common answer of 184 isn't correct.  If authority is between 32 and the maximum of 48 bits, then it must be represented as a hex string, not decimal, and prepended with '0x'.  This means instead of a 15-character string needed to represent the maximum 48 bits in decimal, you actually need a (48 bit / 4 bit + 2) 14 character string, meaning (184 - 15 + 14) 183 characters are required for whole SID string.  For less than 32 bits, decimal format is used (maximum 10 decimal characters).

Comment: Interestingly, even some of MS own code doesn't honour this.  The .NET Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier constructor accepts the hex format, but the ToString() method always outputs in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

While 184 looks correct, on the official docs there is a different value:

> SID - Specifies the security identifier of the domain account. SID is a string with a maximum length of 256 characters.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-offlineuseraccounts-offlinedomainaccounts-offlinedomainaccount-sid#:~:text=SID%20is%20a%20string%20with%20a%20maximum%20length%20of%20256%20characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-offlineuseraccounts-offlinedomainaccounts-offlinedomainaccount-sid#:%7E:text=SID%20is%20a%20string%20with%20a%20maximum%20length%20of%20256%20characters).