# Sid in USER_TOKEN lifetime

Tags: c, winapi, lifetime, sid

The [`TOKEN_USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_user) structure contains a pointer to a `Sid` structure. How long does this SID live (alternatively, where is the SID stored in memory)? Is the SID stored in the `TOKEN_USER` structure (so it lives until this structure is dropped)?

###### Context

To obtain the current user SID, I open the process token using [`OpenProcessToken()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken).

Then I write the user `TOKEN_USER` to an allocated buffer using [`GetTokenInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) with `TokenUser` as the token information class.

A pointer to the SID is in the `User.Sid` field, but the documentation doesn't say where the SID is stored.

Will the SID pointer remain valid when the process token is closed? Or when the `TokenUser` structure is deallocated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetTokenInformation() first call. What for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670984/gettokeninformation-first-call-what-for), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671015/902497). The pointer points back into the memory you allocated and passed to GetTokenInformation, so you control the lifetime.

Comment: *Or when the TokenUser structure is deallocated?* - you allocate it by self. and only you can (and must at some time) deallocate it. and the sid of token is invariant

Comment: *"must at some time deallocate it"* - A statement written by someone that doesn't understand [the purpose of garbage collection](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203).

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, thanks, that helps. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. @RbMm I know. With "is deallocated" I meant when I deallocate it. The point is, the pointer could point e.g. somewhere into the process token instead of into the `TokenUser` allocation.